# Custom field error from try/except in Django view?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, geopy

I have a form for geocoding an address in my app. If a non-address is entered, the geocoder raises a "GQueryError". Using try/except I'd like to catch this error and send a custom error back to the form that would show up in the "errorlist" like the other errors and be appropriately displayed and styled. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write a `clean_field_name` method and in it capture the error and raise a `ValidationError` e.g

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    ...
    # rest of the form
    ...

    def clean_address(self):
        address = self.cleaned_data['address']
        try:
            address = geo_clean(address)
        except GQueryError,e:
            raise forms.ValidationError("ooops you are so wrong, %s!"%e)

        return address
```

Read [how to clean specific fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute)